# Search appears duplicated in AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, autocomplete

I'm having a problem using the Android's AutoCompleteTextView.

AutoComplete is presenting me with duplicate data because it's searching both the name and the email. I would like it to present only one value, either by searching by the name of the contact or by searching for the email.

Basically, I have a list that stores a HashMap containing the name and email of each contact:

```
List<Map<String, String>> contact_list = new ArrayList<>();
```

To fill in the Hashmap, I use a Cursor to help me fetch the information from the Database:

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(ContactTable.SELECT_ALL, null);
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            Map<String, String> contact_info = new HashMap<>();
            contact_info.put("name",     cursor.getString(ContactTable.COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME_IDX));
            contact_info.put("email", cursor.getString(ContactTable.COLUMN_CONTACT_EMAIL_IDX));
            contact_list.add(contact_info);
        }
    }
```

After I add all instances of HashMap to my list, I add this list to a SimpleAdapter and set this adapter in my AutoCompleteTextView:

```
    auto_adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            mContext,
            contact_list,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
            new String[]{"name", "email"},
            new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
    auto_complete.setAdapter(auto_adapter);
```

The threshold has value "1" and was declared in the layout file:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/dialog_participant_name_auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    android:hint="@string/dialog_participant_auto_name"
    android:textColorHint="@color/hint_text_color"
    android:completionThreshold="1"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

It works almost perfectly, but it doubles the value of the query. For example, if I save a contact named "Fulano" and email "fulano@gmail.com", and search for "F", the AutoCompleteTextView returns me two items:

[autoComplete problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrqIh.png)